# Is there a way to list all functions of a module in utop?

Tags: ocaml, utop

In utop, when opening a library (via ~require ...) or when opening a module (via `open Module_name`), is there a way to get the content of the library or module? utop offers this by completion tabs, but I would like to see all the functions at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `utop` you can use the `#show` command. For example

```
utop # #show Stack;;
module Stack :
  sig
    type 'a t
    exception Empty
    val create : unit -> 'a t
    val push : 'a -> 'a t -> unit
    val pop : 'a t -> 'a
    val top : 'a t -> 'a
    val clear : 'a t -> unit
    val copy : 'a t -> 'a t
    val is_empty : 'a t -> bool
    val length : 'a t -> int
    val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
  end
```

Comment: For completeness: in ocaml toplevel, this would be `#show_module Stack;;`

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily in utop, you can use the following:

```
# module type S = module type of Module_of_your_interest;;
module type S =
  sig
    ...
    ...
  end
```

Warning: some modules have really big signatures.

Comment: How can I get the "docstring" of a function? Say I want to know hat Stack.pop does?

Answer (score -1):

If you are interested in function names available in the library you can write:

```
#module S = Library_name;;
```

for example:

```
#module M = String;;
```

The output will be:

> module M :   sig
>       external length : string -> int = "%string_length"
>       external get : string -> int -> char = "%string_safe_get"
>       external set : string -> int -> char -> unit = "%string_safe_set"
>       external create : int -> string = "caml_create_string"
>       val make : int -> char -> string
>       val copy : string -> string
>       val sub : string -> int -> int -> string
>       val fill : string -> int -> int -> char -> unit
>       val blit : string -> int -> string -> int -> int -> unit
>       val concat : string -> string list -> string
>       val iter : (char -> unit) -> string -> unit
>       val iteri : (int -> char -> unit) -> string -> unit
>       val map : (char -> char) -> string -> string
>       val trim : string -> string
>       val escaped : string -> string
>       val index : string -> char -> int
>       val rindex : string -> char -> int
>       val index_from : string -> int -> char -> int
>       val rindex_from : string -> int -> char -> int
>       val contains : string -> char -> bool
>       val contains_from : string -> int -> char -> bool
>       val rcontains_from : string -> int -> char -> bool
>       val uppercase : string -> string
>       val lowercase : string -> string
>       val capitalize : string -> string
>       val uncapitalize : string -> string
>       type t = string
>       val compare : t -> t -> int
>       external unsafe_get : string -> int -> char = "%string_unsafe_get"
>       external unsafe_set : string -> int -> char -> unit
>         = "%string_unsafe_set"
>       external unsafe_blit : string -> int -> string -> int -> int -> unit
>         = "caml_blit_string" "noalloc"
>       external unsafe_fill : string -> int -> int -> char -> unit
>         = "caml_fill_string" "noalloc"   end

After that you can even use M as an alias of String. e.g:

```
# M.concat " " ["one"; "two"; "three"];;
```